# ORACLE EST GMT date issue

Tags: oracle, date

I need to get the count of inventory grouped by date. I used the following query. My issue is that the application finding the data is EST and the db is running in GMT time zone. So when i select a particular date in application it needs to get the corresponding GMT date and get its count. Currently the query im using is

```
SELECT tble.dte, COUNT(DISTINCT INVENTORY_ID)As cmt 
  FROM ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo 
       right join (SELECT 
                   TO_DATE('03/11/2015 04:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 1 + rownum dte 
                     FROM DUAL 
                  CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366 
                      AND 
         TO_DATE('03/11/2015 04:00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 1 + rownum <= 
                         TO_DATE('04/02/2015 03:59:59','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                  ) tble 
              ON tble.dte = (groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN) 
 group by tble.dte
 order by tble.dte desc`
```

But in this case the count is incorrect as 11th march EST = 11March 04:00:00 AM to 12 Mar 03:59:59 GMT. so when i searh for 11th march i need to get the data between the above mentioned date  range from DB. please assist

Comment: Formatting your code would make it much easier to read.  Are you storing data in `date` columns?  `timestamp with time zone` columns?  Or something else?

Comment: DATE_TURNED_IN IS of date DATATYPE IN DB

Comment: OK.  And do you really want to convert that into EST?  Or US/Eastern (which may be EST or EDT)?

Comment: The input to this query ie(to_date(?)) is EST. I want its corresponding GMT date and then count on that date.

Comment: OK.  So `date_turned_in` is **always** EST?  It's never EDT?

Comment: Its GMT in db... but the date to compare from application is EST.

Comment: OK.  `date_turned_in` is implicitly GMT.  You want to search against a date that is implicitly EST.  So the application will never pass in a date that uses daylight savings time (EDT)?

Comment: yes.I need to fetch the data fron db whcich has date in GMT but the passing date is in EST

Comment: What dou you mean by "DB is running in GMT time zone"? In general `DATE` data type does not contain any time zone information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `EST` is your `SESSIONTIMEZONE` you can do it like this:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-02 04:00:00' + ROWNUM * INTERVAL '1' DAY AS DT
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY TIMESTAMP '2015-04-02 04:00:00' + ROWNUM * INTERVAL '1' DAY <= TIMESTAMP '2015-11-03 04:00:00')
SELECT tble.dte, COUNT(DISTINCT INVENTORY_ID)As cmt 
FROM ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo 
   right join t ON FROM_TZ(CAST(dte AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') = DT
```

or more explicitly:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-04-02 04:00:00 EST' + ROWNUM * INTERVAL '1' DAY AS DT
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY TIMESTAMP '2015-04-02 04:00:00 EST' + ROWNUM * INTERVAL '1' DAY <= TIMESTAMP '2015-11-03 04:00:00 EST')
SELECT tble.dte, COUNT(DISTINCT INVENTORY_ID)As cmt 
FROM ATL_GROUNDING_INFO groundinginfo 
   right join t ON FROM_TZ(CAST(dte AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') = DT
```

Comment: getting the error  not a single-group group function

Comment: Forgot the group by clause obviously